# How to load HTML after LoadString() deprecation

Tags: html, .net, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp WinForms on a .NET project and after upgrading on a version greater than 75.x, I cannot use the method "LoadString" any more. I made some research on web for alternative solution but no luck so far. Some info regarding this issue can be found on "https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17231" but it seems that it is not so clear how to solve this problem.

Basically, I was using the above method to load HTML string into the browser (e.g. LoadString("hello world- this is my html", "about:blank")). Now if I use the "LoadHtml" method, I'm getting an empty page.

Did anyone else had a similar issue and found a solution for it?

Comment: Some options are listed at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#loading-htmlcssjavascriptetc-from-diskdatabaseembedded-resourcestream

Comment: Please provide a detailed example of the code you had previously and what you've tried. When you are calling these methods is important. Please be as detailed as possible,  a single line example won't tell me much

Comment: @amaitland the options list you provided was very helpful. Thanks a lot for your help!